# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography

I want my numeric string would be encrypted then decrypt and return as ASCII.
but at decrypt block its giving an error as Invalid length in below static method. my string should be generated in code as xx-xx-xx like this ,Hypen is inserted after every 2 digit.but unable to decrypt ,raise length of data to decrypt is invalid?

how to resolve error please help!

Here Is My Code below: -
  encryptedText=9007315596089 , key= 'This Is MySecure', iv='Encrption' to below method

```
private static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string key, string iv)
{
    //encryptedText = encryptedText.Insert(2, "-");
    int length = encryptedText.Length;
    byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
    byte[] ivBytes = getIVBytes(iv);
    string encrytedTextNew = "";

    //for (int i = 2; i < encrytedTextNew.Length - 1; i += 3)
    //{
    //    if (encrytedTextNew.Count(c => c == '-') >= 3) i++;
    //    encrytedTextNew = encrytedTextNew.Insert(i, "-");
    //}

    char[] encrytArray = encryptedText.ToCharArray(0, encryptedText.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < encryptedText.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            //if (j == 14)
            //{
            //    encrytedTextNew = encrytedTextNew +"-";
            //    break;
            //}
            if (j % 2 == 0)
            {
                encrytedTextNew = encrytedTextNew + encrytArray[i] + "-";
            }
            else
            {
                encrytedTextNew = encrytedTextNew + encrytArray[i];
            }
        }
        else if (i == 0)
        {
            encrytedTextNew = encrytedTextNew + encrytArray[i];
        }
    }

    encrytedTextNew = encrytedTextNew.Remove(encrytedTextNew.Length-1);
    //encrytedTextNew = encrytedTextNew + "7";
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Key = keyBytes;
    aes.IV = ivBytes;
    ICryptoTransform encrypto = aes.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] plainTextByte = Array.ConvertAll<string, byte>(encrytedTextNew.Split('-'), s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16));
    int len = plainTextByte.Length;
    **byte[] CipherText = encrypto.TransformFinalBlock(plainTextByte,0, plainTextByte.Length - 1);**
    return ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(CipherText);
}
```

Comment: I'm not liking how stringly-typed this code is. Encryption/Decryption is based on bytes. About the only sane byte/string conversion to do with encrypted data is Base 64 Encoding/Decoding or Hex. So I'm worried about this code that's adding all kinds of other characters into text that was *already* claimed to a) be encrypted and b) be a string. We definitely need to see the encryption code too to see how closely these operations line up to giving us a chance that round-tripping will work.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever Actually  Sir Code is written by some one else  and i am getting confuse that why it was giving invalid length error at TransFormFinalBlock. They have taken numeric string make it as xx-xx-xx like format ,then they use RijndaelManaged  to decrypt i think and lastly TransFormFinalBlock which converts specified byte array to base 64.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what your input is - I think from looking at your code that perhaps encryptedText is a block of hex values as a string. Is that right? Also I think when you say "Parameter 1 = 9007315596089" that you mean this is the value for `encryptedText`. If that is so might be worth editing to just say that rather than talk about parameter 1, etc. I think it would be a lot clearer.

Comment: Chris  sir i have edited that ,yes mentions data are parameters to method,Actually i am taking numeric string as parameter 1 which is encryptedText ,and for key and iv values the mention above strings. What is happening in code is when i debbug above code before  TransFormFinalBlock i got my numeric string as 90-07-31-55-96-08-9 and at TransFormFinalBlock  it has raise an error  as ' Length of the data to decrypt is invalid'.

Comment: Something has gone wrong on the encryption side if you're passed the string `9007315596089` and it's claimed to be the hex representation of data encrypted with `Rijndael`. Using default settings, you should be using 128 bit blocks which means 16 bytes - whereas `9007315596089` interpreted as hex (strangely missing any `a-f` characters) is only 7 1/2 bytes. You need to talk to the person who produced the encryption side, discuss and agree *exactly* what transformations are taking place pre/post encryption. I'd then suggest you both implement *both* sides and compare intermediate results.